# Creating scatterplot using R

Tags: r

I have imported a pimadata.csv to R, I have to create a scatter plot matrix for the first 8 columns in the pimadata; also have to find two variables that seem to have positive correlations. I used this line of code to create the plot;

```
pairs(pimadata[,1:8])
```

What should I do to show the correction between the variables?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cor()`

```
cor(pimadata[,1:8])
```

Since you did not provide the contents of `pimadata.csv`, I use the `iris` dataset as an example here.

```
head(iris)
pairs(iris[,1:4])
```

[scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNH0k.png)

```
cors <- cor(iris[,1:4])
```

[correction output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS9qG.png)